# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus have a Numlock warning

Tags: login, 16.04, numlock

The newest version of Ubuntu has a new nifty feature: a big exclamation mark warning in the password box when you have Numlock on at login.

[image: Numlock warning at login]

When you mouse over the warning:
[image: Numlock warning at login with mouseover]

Why would the user be concerned about this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, this warning should only be shown for capslock, not numlock.

Comment: I've edited my question to show what it says when you hover the mouse over the exclamation. When you enable Caps Lock it turns to a brighter white warning.
But my thoughts exactly, you only need a warning for Caps Lock

Comment: @ParanoidPanda no, IIRC, the reason is for laptop keyboards, where numlock enables numpad on keys which would otherwise be part of the normal space. And it's not new: there were bugs filed about it in 2012: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/945534

Comment: So they re-enabled this feature that was removed in 12.04? I do not have a laptop keyboard, and most laptops I've had don't do numlock that way. It seems a bit excessive to have this warning for everyone. I always leave numlock on because it's more useful.

Comment: So, is there a way to disable it?

Comment: @brandizzi Apparently no according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1526322.

Comment: Oddly I never noticed this, and that's because it only shows up on my lock screen.  I logged out and it doesn't show on the "logged out" login screen, even if I press the numlock button.  I  never lock my laptop though so I never saw it until now.  Does it show up on everyone's login screen or just the lock screen like me?

Comment: @Dorian I have a couple desktops and I don't have this behavior. It seems logical that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/786081/225694) is correct. I would assume that whether you get it or not is related to keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken it is for laptop users, so they know when the num-pad is on which is usually on the lettered keys as well.